# Swift crash when player gets notification for their turn

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, game-center

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file HATurnBasedMatchHelper.swift, line 244
2021-01-25 20:36:22.317564-0500 QuizApp[14288:4507393] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file HATurnBasedMatchHelper.swift, line 244


func player(_ player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventFor match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool) {
    // Crash on Line 244
    // state of self when using notification
    /*
     self    QuizApp.HATurnBasedMatchHelper    0x0000000281a4c310
         ObjectiveC.NSObject    NSObject
         reachability    QuizApp.Reachability?    0x0000000281a4c7e0
         saveToLoseList    Bool?    false    some
         isMultiplayerGame    Bool?    false    some
         currentMatch    GKTurnBasedMatch?    0x0000000283e29530
         selectedCategory    QuizApp.HACategory?    nil    none
         delegate    QuizApp.HATurnbasedMatchHelperDelegate?    nil    none
         presentingViewController    UIViewController?    nil    none
         myWins    Int64    1
         pendingWins    Int64    0
         takeAnotherChallenge    Bool?    false    some
     */
    /* I added the if condition to check if the VC is nil */
    if self.presentingViewController != nil {
        self.presentingViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.currentMatch = match
    
    let firstParticipant = match.participants[0]
    
    if firstParticipant.lastTurnDate == nil
    {
        delegate.enterNewGame(match: match)
    }
    else{
        var statusString : String? = nil
        var thisParticipant : GKTurnBasedParticipant? = nil
        var otherParticipant : GKTurnBasedParticipant? = nil
        
        for participant in match.participants
        {
            if participant.player?.playerID == GKLocalPlayer.local.playerID
            {
                thisParticipant = participant
            }
            else{
                otherParticipant = participant
            }
        }
        if thisParticipant?.matchOutcome == .quit {

            statusString = "You have Quit this match"
        }
        else if otherParticipant?.matchOutcome == .quit
        {
            statusString = "Opponent has Quit this match"
        }
        else if otherParticipant?.status ==  .declined
        {
            statusString = "Opponent has Declined your challenge"
        }

        if statusString == nil{
            if match.currentParticipant?.player?.playerID == GKLocalPlayer.local.playerID
            {
                // crash here
                // delegat is nil. I posted all values of self above
                delegate.takeTurn(match: match)
            }
            else{
                delegate.layout(match: match)
            }
        }
        else{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Match status\n", message:statusString , preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action) in
                
            }
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentingViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

The exact error is

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: I would need more code to understand the problem but were you not supposed to assign the delegate yourself? It usually needs to be assigned to self or another class which conforms to the protocol

Comment: @KyleBurns do you have time to look at my code?

Comment: Like I said, evidently the delegate isn't being assigned or is being set to nil somewhere in the code. I'd be happy to look over it if you post all of the code that has access to this HATurnBasedMatchHelper instance.

Comment: I am new to Swift but in Visual Studio, I get to see something called "References" that tells me where the class, method/function is being called from. Is there anything like this with Xcode?

Comment: @KyleBurns I selected the function and pressed CMD SHIFT A and select Caller. Xcode shows ?? which means that this function isn't called from another class or method but I did post the entire function above

Comment: It isn't the function causing a problem. It's the delegate that's nil. I need to see the code where you are instantiating the class containing this function, HATurnBasedMatchHelper. Are you familiar with the delegation design pattern?

Comment: @KyleBurns this is instantiated when the player clicks the Notification to start his/her turn. I can't figure out where it's being instantiated from. I don't mind sharing the code with you but not on SO

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: @KyleBurns got git? I have my project on Git. I can invite you. Send me a private message with your email and I'll send you an invite

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to send private messages. Just invite me on git directly. Username is burns534

Comment: added you. You'll see the crash in HATurnBasedMatchHelper.swift line 243. To reproduce, you need to get an notification to let you know it's your turn. Once you tap it, the app crashes or fails to load the UI.

I tried changing the delegate to delegate?.takeTurn and the app doesn't crash BUT it does not load the UI for the match

Comment: I spent like an hour trying to get it to compile but I can't. Put breakpoints on the line where the delegate is nil and on the two lines in the other class where you assign the delegate and make sure the delegates are being assigned before you ever call the function with the error. Cool project by the way. Sorry I couldn't be of more help

Comment: @KyleBurns Thank you for any help you provided. I appreciate it!

Comment: Would you let me know when you do find out?

Comment: I fixed it. Used weak var to initiate the UIView Controller so it won't crash